# How to get empty data from 2 tables by joining

Tags: sql, database

I have 2 tables respectively,emp_data, role_data

EMP_DATA

```
ID    EMPID  EMPNAME ROLEID
1      A01    ABC      1
2      A01    ABC      3
```

ROLE_DATA

```
ROLEID ROLENAME EMPID
 1     SE        A01
 2     SSE       B01
```

When I join these 2 tables, i have to get OUTPUT OF 2 records like the below one

```
EMPID EMPNAME ROLEID ROLENAME
A01    ABC      1      SE
A01    ABC      3      <NULL OR EMPTY>
```

The query what i have written will give output where instead of null in rolename it gives me SE.

```
SELECT ED.EMPID,ED.EMPNAME,ED.ROLEID,RD.ROLENAME 
FROM SYN.EMP_DATA ED,SYN.ROLE_DATA RD 
WHERE ED.EMPID=RD.EMPID
```

Kindly help me in this regard as to how to get the output like i desire.

Thanks in advance

Comment: show your query here

Answer (score 3):

You want a `left join`:

```
select e.EMPID, e.EMPNAME, e.ROLEID, r.ROLENAME
from EMP_DATA e left join
     ROLE_DATA r
     on e.ROLEID = r.ROLEID;
```

By the way, your problem suggests an issue with your database.  `EMP_DATA.ROLEID` should be declared as a foreign key referencing `ROLE_DATA`.  If so, it would be an error to insert a value that is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Show us your code. You have to use LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT emp.EMPID
    ,emp.EMPNAME
    ,emp.ROLEID
    ,ROLE.ROLENAME
FROM EMP_DATA as emp
LEFT JOIN ROLE_DATA as ROLE ON emp.ROLEID = ROLE.ROLEID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
select a.EMPID, a.EMPNAME, a.ROLEID,IFNULL(b.ROLENAME, 'SE') as ROLENAME
from EMP_DATA a
lef join ROLE_DATA b on a.ROLEID=B.ROLEID
```

Comment: The problem states that the result *is* showing "SE" when null is wanted. You're doing the opposite, filling in "SE" where null is desired.